# uploaded doc,docx file can not open in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-framework2, docx, doc

I am trying to upload resume to my website from users.

so i have resticted the file upload too doc,pdf,and docx.

The file upload system is like following image

[cv upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Ajc.png)

after upload when user click on the renamed file name(bellow "choose file" button) the new uploaded file would be download.

PDF is working nice. doc and docx file are upload successfully but can't not open after download.

here is my code snippet from cvAction file:-

```
$request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $post_data = $request->getPost();
        $nonFile = $request->getPost()->toArray();

        $File = $this->params()->fromFiles('attachment');

        if ($File['name'] != "") {
            $post_data = array_merge($nonFile, array('attachment' => $File['name']));
            $size = new Size(array('max' => '1MB')); //minimum bytes filesize 

            $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
            $adapter->setValidators(array($size), $File['name']);

            $extensionvalidator = new \Zend\Validator\File\Extension(array('extension' => array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx')));
            $adapter->setValidators(array($extensionvalidator), $File['name']);

            if (!$adapter->isValid()) {

                $dataError = $adapter->getMessages();
                $error = array();
                foreach ($dataError as $key => $row)
                    $message .= $row;

                // $form->setMessages(array('fileupload' => $error));

                $is_validation_error = 1;
            } else {
                //$adapter->setDestination(dirname(__DIR__) . '/assets');
                $adapter->setDestination('public/upload/cv');

                $extension = pathinfo($File['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $new_file_name = strtolower($full_name) . "_" . date('dmyHis') . '.' . $extension;

                $adapter->addFilter('File\Rename', array(
                    'target' => $adapter->getDestination() . '/' . $new_file_name,
                    'overwrite' => true
                ));

                $adapter->receive($File['name']);

                /*
                  if ($adapter->receive($File['name'])) {

                  }
                 */
            }
        } else {
            $new_file_name = $cv_check["upload_cv"];
        }
```

plz help to resolve the issue. thanks in advance

Comment: Once check _public/upload/cv_ contain your already uploaded file? If not then you can check for folder permission.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd: yes there is several old uploaded files but it couldn't an issue because every new file is rename before upload. folder permission is also ok. problem is only with doc/docx files. doc/docx file cannot open after download

Comment: @Wilt: would u plz give an example where/how to set mime-type in my code?

Comment: I am not sure where it goes wrong. What I meant was that if you cannot open the `doc`/`docx` file there is probably a `mime-type` issue. It could also be an issue on client side when downloading. Just check the `mime-type` in the different steps in your upload/download process...